# PhpUnit and string

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I started learning PhpUnit and testing. I have a method which returns string, how I can write a test to check if this method returns string. Here is the code I have at this moment:

Method:

```
 /**
 * @return string
 */
public function living()
{
    return 'Happy!';
}
```

Test:

```
 public $real;
public $expected;

public function testLiving()
{
    $this->expected = 'Happy';
    $this->real = 'Speechless';
    $this->assertTrue($this->expected == $this->real);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$this->assertTrue($this->expected == $this->real);
```

is the same as

```
$this->assertEquals($this->expected, $this->real);
```

See https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.assertions.html#appendixes.assertions.assertEquals

Both check if given variables are equal.

You could check if variable is string

```
$this->assertTrue(is_string($this->real));
```

Comment: They're the same when they pass, but when assertEquals fails, it will tell you where the difference is, whereas assertTrue will just tell you that false is not true.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `$this->assertInternalType` to check for type of the data, and if you want to test such functions use **Test Doubles** or **Mocking Object**.

Here is the code giving full demo on how you can test:

```
//Your Class
class StringReturn {
    public function returnString()
    {
        return 'Happy';
    }
}


//Your Test Class
class StringReturnTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testReturnString()
    {
        // Create a stub for the SomeClass class.
        $stub = $this->getMockBuilder('StringReturn')
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->getMock();

        // Configure the stub.
        $stub->method('returnString')
        ->willReturn('Happy');


        $this->assertEquals('Happy', $stub->returnString());
        $this->assertInternalType('string', $stub->returnString());
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Test check only positive.
You need check negative too.

```
public function testLiving()
{
    $classWithLivingMethod = new ClassWithLivingMethod;
    $this->assertTrue(is_string($classWithLivingMethod->living()));
    $this->assertEquals('Happy', $classWithLivingMethod->living());
}
```